# return a derivated QTreeWidgetItem

Tags: qt, qtreewidgetitem

I think that this is not a question regarding especially Qt but a quaestion of a lack of programming expeience.

I derived a class from QTreeWidgetItem and I added some bolean flags. When i initialize a QTreeWidget I add two of them by

```
_NewItem1=MyQTreeWidgetItem(_treewidget);
```

than later I add some items by

```
_NewItem1_1=MyQTreeWidgetItem(_NewItem1);
_NewItem1_1->boleanvalue1=true;
```

If I later want to return these Items I call

```
(MyQTreeWidgetItem)_NewItem1->child(i)
```

but this of course just returns me a MyQTreeWidgetItem with newly initialized bolean flags.

Do I have to override the child function to retun the true Items which I initialized earlier?

Comment: If you added the created element to a widget, and you ask the widget to get your child with the index i, then of course you get the same object you put in earlier. The children are stored in a collection, and usually a collection of pointers. Your cast is btw wrong, it should be '(MyQTreeWidgetItem*)parent->child(i)'

Answer (score 1):

`_NewItem1->child(i)` returns pointer to `QTreeWidgetItem`, which is a base class for `MyQTreeWidgetItem`. You have cast is safely to `MyQTreeWidgetItem`, taking into account it may be also real `QTreeWidgetItem`. This is achieved with [dynamic_cast](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/) in C++, which checks type at runtime.

```
QTreeWidgetItem *item = _NewItem1->child(i);
MyQTreeWidgetItem *myItem = dynamic_cast<MyQTreeWidgetItem>(item);
if (myItem) {
    qDebug() << myItem->boleanvalue1;
} else {
    qDebug() << item << "is not of type MyQTreeWidgetItem";
}
```

On the other hand, type-casting operator `()` allows to convert any type into any other type without any checking, if this kind of conversion is possible. Like, for example, you've converted pointer to `QTreeWidget` into object of type `MyQTreeWidgetItem`. The subsequent access to the variable will produce either a run-time error or a unexpected result.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I now use a dynamic cast for that purpose. But I still do not get the correct value for my item. I initialize the bolean value to true, but when i get the item returned the value is false.

Comment: From the code bits you've provided, you set boleanvalue1 for _NewItem1_1 and try to check it for i-th child of _NewItem1, which apparently is not the same item.